# Push segue behaves like a Modal Segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a table view, where the cell pushes to another ViewController. When run, it has a modal transition instead of a push one. I've tried changing the type of segue and embedding the detailview in a navigation controller yet it remains the same.

My project is structured:

TabBarController --> NavigationController --> ViewController(TableView) --(push) --> ViewController

[image]

Comment: Your FitnessApp VC has 2 outgoing segues. Which one is associated with the table view cell?

Comment: @MarkKrenek Sorry for the confusion, the one named 'ExerciseDetailViewController' is linked to the table view cell